# How to prove If R, S are relations, the relation (R and S)$\implies$ R, (R and S)$\implies$ S are true.

Tags: logic

If R, S are relations, the *relations* (R and S)$\implies$ R, (R and S)$\implies$ S are *true*. If also R is true and S is true, then (R and S) is true.

This is the fifth theorem that follows **Logical axioms and tautologies** in books of Roger Godement's *Algebra*. My understanding of this theorem is that (R and S) implies R or (R and S) implies S is always true regardless of whether (R and S) is true or not. But I find it hard to prove it based on the Axiom. Could someone please show me the step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the book's definition of operators we have : $R \:and\ S\equiv not(not(R)\:or\ not(S))$;

and axiom 2 is  $R \implies (R \:or\ S)$.

Using ($TL\ 4$) : $ (R \implies S) \iff (not(S) \implies not(R))$ on the second axiom we obtain :

$$R \implies (R \ or \ S) \iff not(R \ or \ S) \implies not(R)$$

Then substituting $R = not(K)$ and $S = not(Q)$ we obtain :

$$not((not(K) \ or \ not(Q)) \implies (not(not(K)) \implies K$$

in the last implication we used ($TL\ 3$) : $R \iff not(not(R))$.

so we have:  $ K \ and \ Q \implies K$. $\:\:\fbox{}$

The same can be done for $K \ and \ Q \implies Q$.